# SQL Server 2014 Reporting Services Configuration Manager Crash

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008, reporting

When I open SQL Server 2014 Reporting Services Configuration Manager, It crashes. The Configuration Screen cannot open. Error is attached and Event Viewer log is below. Thanks for your help

[image: error Detail]

Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: CLR20r3
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: rsconfigtool.exe
P2: 12.0.0.0
P3: 5b91da0d
P4: mscorlib
P5: 2.0.0.0
P6: 5e7591b8
P7: 20aa
P8: 7
P9: N3CTRYE2KN3C34SGL4ZQYRBFTE4M13NB
P10:

Attached files:

These files may be available here:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_rsconfigtool.exe_dbdfed65c4d7ca04c5f70acefbc812132ab48f1_00000000_0dada991

Analysis symbol:
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: 018fc01f-03bb-11eb-816b-005056a0b91a
Report Status: 2048
Hashed bucket:

Comment: Is there any chance you've been editing the RSReportServer.config file by hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an syntax error on Machine.config. That's why we got this error. After fixing the config error, this problem solved